# Extracting videos in mp4 format from SWF files

Tags: python, flash, video, ffmpeg

I am working on swf files which are actually video getting played on browser. I can't  work directly on them. The input for my Python code is video in .mp4 or .mov format. How to convert or extract video from those swf files? I tried out using FFMPEG but I am getting only audio not visual part after conversion.

The `ffmpeg` command that I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i source.swf out.mp4
```

I am writing code in Python and my OS is Windows 2007.

Comment: ffmpeg does not decode actionscript or related vector graphics in SWF. Screencap of SWF as its playing is the common method for getting the video.

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you for your answer but Is n't there any python library which can do the same?

Comment: @halfer Sorry for using such words bt for me, it was an urgent task to complete on time.

Comment: Do you think that other people do not have their own deadlines? Do you think that your deadlines should apply to volunteers?

Comment: How big is the swf file (in megabytes) and also how long the video (time)? I doubt they/you put every single video frame as pictures embeded inside the swf. Are you sure the swf itself does not have code to load some external MP4 or FLV video file?